# Argo events Authorization to eventbus internal NATS

Tags: authorization, token, nats.io, argo-events

I am trying to connect Argo event source to internal Argo eventbus NATS server. I configured event source

```
spec:
  nats:
    subtask-create:
      url: nats://eventbus-default-stan-svc:4222
      jsonBody: true
      subject: task-create-finished
      auth:
        clusterID: eventbus-default
        token:
          name: client-auth
          key: eventbus-default-client
```

but creating eventsource cannot finish and eventbus-controller log contains

```
{"level":"info","ts":1634109821.5641801,"logger":"argo-events.eventsource-controller","caller":"eventsource/resource.go:92","msg":"deployment is created","namespace":"argo-events","eventSource":"my-nats","deploymentName":"my-nats-eventsource-6x9fl"}
```

Which log can give me more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem  is wrong token information. The right way is

```
spec:
  nats:
    subtask-create:
      url: nats://eventbus-default-stan-svc:4222
      jsonBody: true
      subject: task-create-finished
      auth:
        token:
          name: nats-eventbus-token
          key: client-auth
```

so **key** is name of key inside of secret which is named in element **name**.
The token has to be inserted in decoded form without quotes and tag. Put it into file and create like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic nats-eventbus-token --from-file=client-auth=file
```